# javascript object to jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a code for forms, as have a lot of forms need to simplify the way to mask fields in the forms.For I made a class that encapsulates the ids of the fields and assign specific interactions for each.

I have code:

```
var Mask=(function() {

var me=this;    

var eventInterator;
var func; 
var fields;

function Mask(fd,ev,fn){

  this.setFunction(fd);
  this.setFunction(fn);
  this.setEvent(ev);
  this.execute();
}

Mask.prototype.setFields = function(fd){

   fields=fd;

}

Mask.prototype.setFunction= function(fn){

    func=fn;    

}

Mask.prototype.setEvent= function (ev){

    eventInterator=ev;      

}

Mask.prototype.execute = function(){

    for (var i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        loadEvent(fields[i]);       
    }

}   

function loadEvent(field){

    $(me+' '+field).on(eventInterator,function() {  

            func();
    });

}

return Mask;

})();
```

when I run the follow code:

```
 function doSomeThing(){
   alert("hi");

 }
var fields = ['#field1','#field2','#field3','#field4'];

var mask = new Mask(fields,"keyup",doSomeThing);
```

I receive the error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Window]

how can I set the object of javascript class for the jquery selector?

Comment: what line is the error on?

Comment: What happens when you correct `this.setFunction(fd);` to `this.setFields(fd);`?

Comment: Not related to the question, but I do not see how your `Mask` abstraction is useful vs `$('#field1, #field2, #field3, #field4').keyup(doSomeThing);` or `$(fields.join(', ')).keyup(doSomeThing)` if selectors have to be dynamic.

Comment: Indeed, by this way the jquery looks like the same thing

Comment: but I'm curious about using javascript object in jquery

Comment: you are rigth about change this.setFunction(fd); to this.setFields(fd), it was my mistake, when I passed the code here

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems

First `this.setFunction(fd);` should be `this.setFields(fd);`

Second
In your `Mask` function, `me` refers to the `window` object, since it is an object `me + ' ' + field` will return `[object Window] #field1`, that is why you are getting th error.

So change `$(me+' '+field)` to `$(field)`

---

Also as @plalx said, your use of local variables is useless as every instance of `Mask` will override previous values

Comment: There's more than 2 problems. The entire module doesn't make any sense. All the private module variables will get shared across instances.

Comment: The classical implementation is now fine, but honestly that code is useless... http://jsfiddle.net/2gLf52mm/2/

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for your attention. I've tried this alternative, changed     $(me+' '+field) to $(field). when I do that, the jquery  overlaps all the instances of implemented function to the last  function object created. So I want to know if it is possible to add the javascript object as identifier

Comment: you are rigth about What change this.setFunction(fd); to this.setFields(fd), it was my mistake, when I passed the code here.